# Multivariate Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Suppose $f(x,w)\not=0$ for all $x,w\in H^+\cup H^-$ (open upper and lower half planes) and $f$ is a multivariate entire function. Must there exist univariate entire functions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ with only real zeros, and multivariate entire function $g$ such that $$f(x,w)=\phi_1(x)\phi_2(w)e^{g(x,w)}?$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is an entire function of two complex variables?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry.

Comment: Also, for 2) there are *two* real lines in question. I tried interpreting it liberally.

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure what you are aiming for here.

2) Sure. Take for example $f(x,w) = xwe^{x+w}$

3) No. See 2)

Comment: Good example. Maybe we are looking to show that $f$ is factorable as univariate functions with only real zeros together with an exponential part, $e^{g(x,y)}$.